# Facebook linked website interaction issues

Tags: facebook, responsive-design, swipe, meta-tags, openseadragon

Looking for a solution on how to prevent an annoying usability issue introduced by Facebook's built-in web browser on mobile (iOS app).
Pages opened from links in posts are embedded/floated over FB content and are 'slippery' in that user can easily accidentally swipe out of it.

Any user interaction on the embedded browser such as Openseadragon canvas easily pops the user out of the page back to FB.
The only way to prevent this is removing the responsive meta tag from the targeted page, which breaks responsiveness too.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Video of issue here:
https://vimeo.com/758945183

Any ideas?